# Difference of type between "fun" and "&fun"?

Tags: c++, types, language-lawyer, function-pointers

Do expressions `fun` and `&fun` have the same type or not?

Consider the following code:

```
template <typename Check, typename T>
void check(T)
{
    static_assert(is_same<Check, T>::value);
}

void fun()
{}

check<void(*)()>(fun);
check<void(*)()>(&fun);

cout << typeid(fun).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(&fun).name() << endl;
```

Both assertions succeed which suggests that both expressions have the same type. However, `typeid`s return different results:

```
FvvE
PFvvE
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 30):

Both assertions succeed because they are applied to the type `T` deduced from function argument. In both cases it will be deduced as a pointer to function because functions decay to a pointer to function. However if you rewrite assertions to accept types directly then first one will fail:

```
static_assert(is_same<void(*)(), decltype(fun)>::value);
static_assert(is_same<void(*)(), decltype(&fun)>::value);
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MFyGXZKxiDddQ9qk)

Answer (score 18):

`fun` and `&fun` refer to the same type because of [function to pointer conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Function_to_pointer), which is performed in `check<void(*)()>(fun);`; but [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) is an exception.

(emphasis mine)

> Lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, or **function-to-pointer conversions are not performed**.

And why the function to pointer conversion is performed for `check<void(*)()>(fun);`, because in [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction),

> Before deduction begins, the following adjustments to **P** and **A** are made:
>
> 1) If **P** is not a reference type,
>
> - if **A** is an array type, ...;
> - otherwise, if **A** is a function type, **A** is replaced by the pointer type obtained from function-to-pointer conversion;

`check()` takes parameter by value, then function-to-pointer conversion is performed and the deduced type of `T` will be the function pointer too, i.e. `void(*)()`.

Answer (score 7):

When you use a function name as an expression, it *decays* to a pointer to itself. So `fun` will be the same as `&fun`.

As for the `typeid` thing, from [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid):

> Lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, or **function-to-pointer** conversions are not performed.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

Comment: Why do `typeid`s return different type names?

Comment: @NPS Because `function-to-pointer conversions are not performed.`

Comment: [conv.func]/1 says it _can_ ("An lvalue of function type T can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T ”. The result is a pointer to
the function."), but I cannot find a rule saying it _does_.

Comment: @YSC It *does* in template argument deduction; `check` takes argument by value and the deduced type `T` will be the function pointer.

Comment: What does it mean "use as an expression"? When is that? When is it not?